# How can I pass options to AngularStrap timepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs and after some serious effort, I finally got the AngularStrap [DatePicker](http://mgcrea.github.com/angular-strap/#/datepicker) and [TimePicker](http://mgcrea.github.com/angular-strap/#/timepicker) to work.

Now I'd like to pass some options to the TimePicker to e.g. use 24-hour format (`showMeridian = false`). Whereas the DatePicker can be configured with HTML5 data attributes (e.g. `data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" data-date-weekstart="1"`), this seems not to work with the TimePicker.

How can I pass options to the TimePicker?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration options for both plugins can be set with the use of data attributes.

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker"/>
    <input id="timepicker" data-template="modal" data-minute-step="1" data-modal-backdrop="true" type="text"/>
</div>
```